# JScroll and JSeditor issues

Tags: java, swing

I'm completely new to using Swing applications so if it looks like I have no idea what I am doing, I don't. 
I'm trying to display a fixed webpage but I am getting an error `"The constructor JScrollPane(JEditorPane) is undefined"` when I have looked online and seen multiple people using the same line as me with no issues. Any ideas?

```
URL url = new URL  ("http://stackoverflow.com/");                    
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fixed URL");
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();

jep.setPage(url);
jep.setEditable(false); 
jep.setContentType("Text/html");

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep); //ERROR HERE   
frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane); //THUS CREATING ONE HERE

frame.setSize(640, 480);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issues with your code, I don't get the exception that you have mentioned. Though the web page was not displayed in the Frame. But when I removed the below content type setting, I was able to see the web page in the Frame. The issue with content type setting is you need to set.

```
jep.setContentType("text/html"); instead of the below.

jep.setContentType("Text/html");
```

The below code works and I was able to see the page. Though its not formatted well.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
```

public class Web {

```
public Web() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL  ("http://stackoverflow.com/");                    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fixed URL");
    JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();

    jep.setPage(url);
    jep.setEditable(false);
    jep.setContentType("text/html");

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep); //NO ERROR HERE   
    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane); //THUS CREATING ONE HERE


    frame.setSize(640, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Web obj = new Web();
}
```

}

Comment: It's still not displaying just giving me that error, it may be my project setup and properties. Do you know what settings they should be for this to work?

Comment: Did you try my code, it has the entire class implementation ?

Comment: Could you try to run the java from command prompt instead like below.    You should have set your java home in your environment variables to run javac and java commands from command prompt.    C:\java_files>javac Web.java

C:\java_files>java Web

Comment: I'm unable to as im on a restricted computer. I'm now pretty sure its a problem with the projects settings but I have no idea where

Comment: Maybe can you edit your code in the question, so that I can see the entire implementation.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ? and does a simple java program work for you ? are you able to import all the classes which I have mentioned in my solution ?

Comment: A simple one works and I can import all the classes. I'm currently using Eclipse using JavaSE-1.6. The code you edited is the entire implementation also there's nothing else in the project or class. When the problematic lines are commented out a blank frame appears also